# Faster way to parse 400,000 strings and load into a user defined table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, console-application

I have to parse around 40,000 strings and load into DataTable  it is taking like forever to parse the string and load. Could any one suggest me a faster method.?

```
//sameple string
    00001000200|something|something|999999999999|999999999999

var loadNdcs = new List<string>();
DataTable table=new DataTable(); 
table.BeginLoadData();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] vals = line.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (!loadNdcs.Contains(vals[0]))
    {
        if (vals[3] == "99999999")
            vals[3] = null;
        if (vals[4] == "99999999")
            vals[4] = null;
        table.LoadDataRow(vals, true);
        loadNdcs.Add(vals[0]);                       
    }
}
table.EndLoadData();
```

Comment: Have you measured the time consumed by various parts of your code to determine where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Actually the application is really big... The bottleneck is this part of the  application  rest of it is working fine..

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of breaking out the time needed for parsing, manipulating the `DataTable`, checking for previously loaded values, ... . Then see which will give you the biggest bang for the buck in optimization.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `LoadDataRow` _Finds and updates a specific row. If no matching row is found, a new row is created using the given values._ Sounds expensive. Is this checking necessary?

Comment: You generally don't want to load 400000 into a data table. This structure is not suited for large volumes of data. Large being over 100K. If you run the profiler, it shows you performance bottlenecks to the exact line of code that brings everything down. Please tell us which line of code it is, out of those you provided.

Comment: @HABO I tried as you said and the bottle is the condition checking for "99999999"

Comment: <gobsmacked>You measured performance: (1) as shown, (2) with the inner `if` statements removed and (3) with the inner `if` statements removed, but setting the `vals` to `null`? And it was the string comparisons that was slowing down the code?!</gobsmacked>

Answer (score 2):

One optimization would be to use a `HashSet` with O(1) lookup instead of a list.

```
var loadNdcs = new HashSet<string>();
...
if (loadNdcs.Add(vals[0]))
{
 ...
}
```

You might also want to use `table.Rows.Add(vals)` instead of `table.LoadDataRow(vals, true)` to avoid unnecessary update if that is not needed. Also, if you have a `table.EndLoadData()` you probably want a `table.BeginLoadData()`

Comment: As it is `LoadDataRow` acts as a `BeginLoadData` but with `Rows.Add` it may do some good.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is coming in from a file, I would not load the whole file, but use a `System.IO.StringReader` and call `ReadLine()`.

Will it be faster?  Maybe.  Will it use less memory?  Definitely.